# Comma delimited list to string sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, replace, string-concatenation

i need to convert the following values from a variable:

```
1234,1234,12345,12346,1344,4564
```

to this:

```
'1234','1234','12345','12346','1344','4564'
```

using an SQL function.

I have tried:

```
DECLARE @VAL AS VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @VAL = '1234,1234,12345,12346,1344,4564'

DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr+',' ,'') + @VAL
SELECT @listStr AS 'List'
GO
```

But i get:

```
1234,1234,12345,12346,1344,4564
```

Comment: `select '''' + replace(@yourvariable,',',''',''') + ''''`

Comment: COALESCE returns the first non-null value from its arguments. It's not related to string manipulation. Additionally, DON'T use `varchar(max)`, it's intended for use as a BLOB, not as a convenient string without size

Comment: Ugh, why? Are you then going to put `@listStr` into something like `WHERE column IN (' + @listStr + ')`? You really should look into table-valued parameters or, if you are on < 2008, splitting strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT '''' + REPLACE('1234,1234,12345,12346,1344,4564', ',', ''',''') + '''';
```

Check this **[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/42450)**

**OUTPUT**

```
|                                    COLUMN_0 |
|---------------------------------------------|
| '1234','1234','12345','12346','1344','4564' |
```

**EDIT**

Use User defined function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufnReplace(@Val VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) 
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT @Val = '''' + REPLACE(@Val, ',', ''',''') + '''';
    RETURN @Val;
END;

SELECT dbo.ufnReplace('1234,1234,12345,12346,1344,4564');
```

Comment: whats UDF? Scalar_Function

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @VAL AS VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @VAL = '1234,1234,12345,12346,1344,4564'
SELECT '''' + REPLACE(@VAL,',',''',''') + ''''
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `REPLACE()` and `CONCAT()`:

```
select concat("\'", replace('1234,1234,12345,12346,1344,4564', ',', "\',\'"), "\'")
```